# Is there a way to bundle an external .exe dependancy (ffmpeg.exe) into pyinstaller's .exe?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an audio manipulation utility which uses the ffmpeg.exe in one of the python packages through python system pipeline.
The ffmpeg file is in my local project

I've read that you can bundle DLL-s and other data files like images or text, but haven't seen a solution for this.

The optimal solution would be that no installer would be needed and you could run the utility from cmd without any dependency - this includes having ffmpeg pre-installed.

Is there a way to bundle the ffmpeg.exe into the .exe file which is created by pyinstaller or maybe there's another solution?

Comment: Note that doing this, *especially* for ffmpeg, has legal consequences you might not want depending on the relevant jurisdiction. There's a reason major open-source projects (like Audacity) often don't bundle ffmpeg, but instead allow it to be installed out-of-band.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this and intending to comply. I will create an open repository and post information about the GPL licenced FFmpeg soft on there.

Comment: Also found this question: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/can-i-use-distribute-lgpl-command-line-software-in-mine-that-isnt-lgpl  
  
I would think that I'm in the same boat as that OP.

Comment: In the "*especially* for ffmpeg" addendum, I actually was referring to patent encumbrances rather than copyright.

Comment: That said, the more immediate impact here is that it requires some adjustments to how you're distributing content that slow startup time. pyinstall *can* basically extract a bunch of files to a temporary directory every time your program runs, but obviously, that's not great from a performance perspective.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback! This option doesn't seem to be working out. I'll go along with creating an installer for this app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually package .exe files (and any other types of files - from the pyinstaller docs I could understand that only .dlls and such can be bundled like this, thus this question) into the executable using the "binaries" option in the pyinstaller's .spec file like:

```
binaries=[('.\\prerequisites\\', 'prerequisites')],
```

In this case, when using the --onefile or -F parameter, the "prerequisites" folder's contents from the .spec file location are packed into the .exe and upon executing it, they are unpacked into the temporary MEIxxxx folder into a folder named "prerequisites". The executable can communicate with the files located there.